# Least positive integer

Tags: real-analysis

The smallest positive integer in the set $\{ 24x+ 60y+2000z | x,y,z \in \mathbb Z\}$? I feel that $24.1+60.33+2000.-1=4$ is the answer. How we ensure this?

Comment: Yes, it is $\gcd(24,60,2000)$

Comment: $24x+60y+2000z = 4(6x+15y+500z)$ so every number in the set is a multiple of $4$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542: Perfect argument ( I was thinking about it too :) ), why don't you write it up as a solution?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 - nice argument-every number in the set is a multiple of 4, and 4 is there-thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n$ are integers, not all $0$, then the smallest positive integer of the form $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\cdots +a_n x_n$, where the $x_i$ range over the integers, is $\gcd(a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n)$.

The case $n=2$ is often called [Bézout's Identity.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) For general $n$, the result can be proved using induction, starting from  Bézout's Identity.

In your particular problem, we have $n=3$, and $\gcd(24,60,2000)=4$, so indeed $4$ is the least positive integer representable as $24x+60y+2000z$.